# clearInterval and setting variable to null not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Despite having `supportchatinterval = null;` AND `clearInterval(supportchatinterval);` in my code below (see `onBlur()` and `onFocus()` ) every 5000ms the function is still loading getTableSupport.php at the same setInterval (see `checkForChangesSupport()`. When the function onBlur is set I want to stop the setInterval until `onFocus` is called again.

```
<script>

supportchatinterval = 5000;

$(document).ready(function(){
    checkForChangesSupport();
    setTimeout(checkForChangesSupport, supportchatinterval);
});

function checkForChangesSupport() {
   $.get("getCountSupport.php", function(response) {
      if(response == 1) {
         refreshTableSupport();
      }
setTimeout(checkForChangesSupport, supportchatinterval)
   });
}

function refreshTableSupport(){
    $('#tableHolderSupport').load('getTableSupport.php');
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function onBlur(){
document.body.className = 'blurred';
$.get("afk.php?afk=1");
supportchatinterval = null;
clearInterval(supportchatinterval);
};

function onFocus() {
document.body.className = 'focused';
$.get("afk.php?afk=0");
    supportchatinterval = 5000;
refreshTableSupport();
}

</script>
```

Comment: 1) You're mixing `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. 2) `setTimeout` returns the timeout id.

Comment: Thanks I'm apparently blind

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with this question, please remove the tag :)

Comment: Why are you editing the answer into your question? Please don't do that, it's confusing.

Comment: ***Please***, stop including the code from my answer in your question. *You're invalidating all the answers this way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no interval to clear, since the new timeout is created each time `checkForChangesSupport()` runs. Either way, `supportchatinterval` is just an integer and can't be "cleared".

To stop that, you could introduce a flag and check whether the function should run or not. Also, you should call `checkForChangesSupport()` to start the timer again.

```
<script>

supportchatinterval = 5000;
var flag = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    checkForChangesSupport();
    setTimeout(checkForChangesSupport, supportchatinterval);
});

function checkForChangesSupport() {
   if(flag){
      $.get("getCountSupport.php", function(response) {
         if(response == 1) {
            refreshTableSupport();
         }
         setTimeout(checkForChangesSupport, supportchatinterval)
      });
   }
}

function refreshTableSupport(){
    $('#tableHolderSupport').load('getTableSupport.php');
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function onBlur(){
document.body.className = 'blurred';
$.get("afk.php?afk=1");
flag = 0;
};

function onFocus() {
document.body.className = 'focused';
$.get("afk.php?afk=0");
flag = 1;
checkForChangesSupport();
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is embarrassing let me give this a shot and read over the documentation regarding clearInterval. I'll accept it if all goes well. Thank you. Sorry.

Comment: Someone pointed out im using setTimeout in my function above should I change it to setInterval?

Comment: Better flip your last two statements. Otherwise, you're calling `clearInterval(null);`

Comment: @aquinas Haha, indeed. Didn't even notice.

Comment: @mich Looks like that, and I've also included it in my answer.

Comment: Can you append your answer with what I posted above? I feel like I just created more issues some how. This is frustrating.

Comment: @michelle Sorry, I've totally misread your question! Going to edit my answer.

Comment: So for onBlur i set it to checkForChangesSupport = null; and for onFocus I set checkForChangesSupport = 5000; onBlur stops it which is great, but onFocus does nothing. * I edited my code above

Comment: @michelle I see, a second please.

Comment: Yeah I don't get why this is happening. onBlur works as intended, onFocus doesn't work. I edited my code above. It should work even if refreshTableSupport(); isn't there.

Comment: @michelle Updated. Please stop editing your question to include the updated code. The question should only show the problem, how to solve it is shown in answers.

Comment: I can't believe it finally. Victory. Thank you so much. Sorry to stress you out.

Answer (score 1):

`supportchatinterval` in your case has NOTHING to do with the timeout that is currently running. All it is how long until the code runs. What you need to do is store the actual timeout id that is generated.

```
theTimeout = setTimeout(checkForChangesSupport, supportchatinterval);
```

and you use that

```
window.clearTimeout(theTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `setInterval`, which is more adequate to your use case.

Then, on blur you can clear it.

Your main issue is confusion between the *delay* of the interval (given as an argument) and its *handle* which is returned when it is set up, and then used as an argument os `clearInterval` to cancel it.

Code:

```
    // This is a delay between function calls, in milliseconds
    supportchatinterval = 5000;
    // This will be the handle returned by setInterval, which be usefull to cancel 
    // it later
    intervalid = null;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        checkForChangesSupport();
        intervalid = setInterval(checkForChangesSupport, supportchatinterval);
    });

    function checkForChangesSupport() {
        $.get("getCountSupport.php", function(response) {
            if (response == 1) {
               refreshTableSupport();
            }
        });
    }

    function refreshTableSupport(){
        $('#tableHolderSupport').load('getTableSupport.php');
    }

    function onBlur(){
        document.body.className = 'blurred';
        $.get("afk.php?afk=1");
        clearInterval(intervalid);
    };

    function onFocus() {
        document.body.className = 'focused';
        $.get("afk.php?afk=0");
        refreshTableSupport();
    }
```

If not only you want to stop calling the interval function on blur, but also when results are present, just call `clearInterval` there :

```
    function checkForChangesSupport() {
        $.get("getCountSupport.php", function(response) {
            if (response == 1) {
               refreshTableSupport();
               clearInterval(intervalid);
            }
        });
    }
```